# Sass doesn't watch changes in @import files

Tags: import, sass, watch

I ran sass --watch styles.scss:styles.css in my css folder.

And it can watch the changes if I make edits to styles.scss

But in the styles.scss, I imported some other sass files from a different folder. And if I make changes in other files, it doesn't watch and translate those changes.

Anyone know a solution?

Comment: watching the entire parent directory and naming your partials with an _ should work

Comment: It seems also, that if you prefix the folder in which the imported `.scss` files are with `_` underscore , then they will not be watched.

Comment: This question was not answered in the linked question @cimmanon

Answer (score 1):

```
// main.scss
@import "./partials/_normalize";
@import "./partials/_article";
```

use a next command to watch both: a folder and a file

```
scss --watch ./partials/ ./main.scss
```

> The underscore lets Sass know that the file is only a partial file and that it should **not** be generated into a CSS file
>   http://sass-lang.com/guide

Comment: Renaming the file will not change anything, it will only prevent a file from being generated.

Comment: @cimmanon it is not about file name, it is about arguments in a command: watch both: a folder and a file together

Comment: Then why do you even mention renaming the files?

Comment: @cimmanon I agree, file name is not in this question, but it's a very popular error in this situation.